# Reading from file more efficient than GameObject.Find?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I'm new to Unity and I started creating a Tower defense game. Currently I can create one level and have monsters spawn and walk along a path I made with empty GameObjects ( Waypoints ). I can also drag and drop Heroes onto certain places called ( PlacePoints ); these are empty GameObjects, too. Here is a picture of my Level_1 prefab:

[Level_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUztt.jpg)

This all works well so far but I read about GameObject.Find and Transform.Find being slow. And since I want to write fast and clean code right from the start, how would I make this faster and more efficient? Here is an example from my LevelManager script:

```
public Transform findPlacePoints()
{
    return GameObject.Find("Level_1(Clone)").transform.Find("PlacePoints");
}
```

The question is, would it be faster to store all the information in a .txt file and load it in my LevelManager and then have each Script find the LevelManager which is a Singleton and ask for specific information? Basicly have the LevelManager act as a distributer? Informtion would be:

- Spawn Times
- Positions of ( SpawnPoints, Waypoints, PlacePoints, etc.)
- Enemy Types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fall into the trap of [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). `GameObject.Find` is only slow if you make it slow (searching lots of objects in your scene). Check out the **Improving Performance of Our Code** section of Unity's [Optimizing Scripts in Unity Games](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-scripts-unity-games) if you want to learn what writing good patterns looks like in Unity. It should provide you with some tips and not have to worry about deep-diving into `GameObject.Find` and disk operation optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer the general tips for optimizing scripts are very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, It really depends on how many items you are searching and how you write the code. From my understanding *direct references*, such as setting a variable in the inspector, is the most efficient way to "find" something in scene.

Unless you are doing it a lot and in updates, it really shouldn't hurt performance *that* much. I would focus my optimization time on not destroying/instantiating, keeping UI updates out of the game loop, and keeping light scripts on frequently used objects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (not saying it is the best) is have a static class just to store some informations (not a monobehaviour) let say Utilities. Have a public GameObject[] waypoints in it. On each of your level, add a script that will overwrite Utilities.waypoints with it's own GameObject[] variable. In the inspector, just drag/drop your waypoints on this script. You can then call Destroy(this) which will delete only the script after completion.